# Mounting a Sharepoint filesystem on Linux using davfs2

Tags: webdav

I am trying to mount a SharePoint (SP) filesystem on Linux using davfs2. I am following the article: http://howto.unixdev.net/Linux-SharePoint.html

First off, I see a lot of questions on SO for mounting SP on Linux. In the future if anyone else tries to do similar thing and face any problem, I would strongly suggest you read the above article which is very useful. It is very thorough and very easy to follow up.

Once I followed the instructions, the SP files showed up on Linux directory where it was supposed to be mounted and everything was just fine.

However, there are two issues that I found:

1. The entire SP file system on Linux shows up with root as owner and group, 
   [image: Linux view]
   even though SharePoint owners are different.
   [image: Sharepoint view]
2. If I modify an existing file in any of the SP sub-directories (as root, since only root has write permission) on Linux side, suddenly the file disappears from SP (and Linux) altogether.

Is this something that looks familiar to anyone? Greatly appreciate any help. I am using davfs2-1.4.7 and neon-0.29.6 (with the patch for neon that fixes space in davfs names) on Ubuntu 10.10.

Comment: The cited link http://howto.unixdev.net/Linux-SharePoint.html does not work anymore. Does anyone know the linked document can be found somewhere else?

Comment: You can restore it from: https://web.archive.org/web/20170810004605/http://howto.unixdev.net/Linux-SharePoint.html

Comment: Note that, according to https://superuser.com/a/1167230/537095 , davfs does not work with Office365 Sharepoint / OneDrive for Business. I followed the cited how-to and end up with "/sbin/mount.davfs: Mounting failed. 403 FORBIDDEN"

Comment: On that same superuser QA above, there's a more recent answer that shows how to setup WebDav using RClone: https://superuser.com/a/1506107/662162 I was able to successfully use RClone to mount Sharepoint libraries.

Answer (score 2):

Can't say I've tried this... but regarding question 1 about the owner/group listing...

When opening a library in Explorer (WebDAV), there is no Creator property... nor is there a way to access the owner as you would with a non-WebDAV drive.

I would also posit that it makes sense not to try to expose that info... as far as SP is concerned, the users might come from anywhere... Active Directory, non-AD LDAP, AspNetSqlMembershipProvider, OpenID, etc... for a WebDAV client to attempt to resolve and understand that could be somewhat futile.

It may also be that the WebDAV spec doesn't even have support for "owners"... it *was* originally written for FrontPage, and only has relatively basic ACL support.

Answer (score 1):

davfs2 works great with SharePoint.

When installing/configuring davfs2 on Linux, be sure to select the option that allows any users to mount (not only root).

When users (other than root) are allowed to mount drives the configuration settings are set here:

~/.davfs2/davfs2.conf 
(The configuration in /etc/davfs2/ is for root only).

Remember to change "use_locks 1" to "use_locks 0" or you will run into some trouble.

Updating ~/.davfs2/secrets file with login details in this format helps.

http://sitename username password

[There is a useful reference here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Davfs2).

Answer (score 0):

it is shows the owner and group as root because `mount -t` requires sudo so you are in principle mounting it as root

you can resolve this by setting the `uid` and `gid` as your user's `uid` and `gid`

you can do this via `/etc/fstab` like this (assuming your `uid` and `gid` are both `1000`)

```
https://domain.sharepoint.com/personal/firstname_lastname_domain_com/Documents /path/to/mountpoint davfs user,rw,noauto,uid=1000,gid=1000,_netdev 0 0
```

after this you can mount with `sudo mount mountpoint`